# Python Pandas find rows that match a pattern using column first characters and a set of values to match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sorted DataFrame by company_name:

```
    company_name
0     A
1     AA
2     abcd
3     abcdu
4     abcdw
5     efg
6     efgu
7     zvttu
8     zvttw
```

I would like to select the rows which have the first 3 letters in common and have the following rows ending with "u" or "w".

Ideally I would like the result to look like this (including the "main" name as an extra column).

```
    company_name,  main_name
0     abcd        abcd       
1     abcdu       abcd
2     abcdw       abcd
3     efg         efg
4     efgu        efg
```

Assume that the start of the company_name has to contain u or w, the end of the name can differ.
Best

Comment: Your resulting example does not satisfy the condition. If you would like to have the first 3 letters in common AND have the following rows ending with "u" or "w", then abcd should not appear in the second column because it does not end with u or w.

Comment: Actually, I would like any that is a full of at least "XYZ" and have the follwing rows being "XYZU", XYZW". Only If "XYZ" was the full first row column value,

Comment: Have taken out the * in case that was your point

Comment: So do you want to keep only those that have at least 1 u or w in the end, and remove those that don't? Like in your example, you want to keep abc and efg, but remove zvt?

Comment: I want to keep only 'u' and 'w' if they match the 'main_name': [match] = [main_name] + 'u' OR 'w'

Comment: I have edited the zvt example to avoid confusion. tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# extract company name by removing ending `uw`
s = df.company_name.str.extract('(.*)[uw]$', expand=False)

company_names = s.fillna(df.company_name)

# valid names are those appear alone and with `uw`
valid_names = s.isna().groupby(company_names).transform('nunique') == 2

df['main_name'] = company_names.where(valid_names)
```

Output:

```
  company_name main_name
0         abcd      abcd
1        abcdu      abcd
2        abcdw      abcd
3          efg       efg
4         efgu       efg
5        zvttu       NaN
6        zvttw       NaN
```

Comment: @NonoLondon works with the sample data. Is `u` and `w` single character or they represent some other pattern?

Comment: no, but they can be capital u or W, does it impact?

Comment: Should not, if you replace `[uw]` with `[UW]`.

Comment: Ok that works for U AND W, I would ideally like U OR W... tx so much for the help

Comment: I know I can run each ... just in case there is a nice way to do the OR

Comment: @NonoLondon it should work with `u` OR `w` if you use `[uw]`?